# Batch file does weird things when run

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am having a lot of issues with this code, could someone explain to me what is wrong? Here is my code:

```
@echo off
cls
set name=Guest
color 0f
:makefolder
cls
echo Setting up FOLDERS...
pause
if exist C:\dasboot GOTO makefiles
if not exist C:\dasboot mkdir C:\dasboot
:makefiles
cls
echo Setting up FILES...
pause
if exist C:\dasboot\password.txt GOTO checkuser
if not exist C:\dasboot\password.txt break>C:\dasboot\password.txt
GOTO checkuser
:checkuser
cls
echo Checking USER FILES...
if exist C:\dasboot\username.txt GOTO start
if not exist C:\dasboot\username.txt break>C:\dasboot\username.txt
echo.
echo DONE. OK.
echo.
pause
GOTO start
:start
echo --------------------------------------
echo Welcome %name%, to Das Boot v.0.1a BETA
echo --------------------------------------
echo.
pause
GOTO username
:username
cls
color 0a
if not exist C:\dasboot\username.txt if not exist C:\dasboot\password.txt GOTO setstats
if exist C:\dasboot\username.txt set /p name=<C:\dasboot\username.txt
if exist C:\dasboot\password.txt set /p password=<C:\dasboot\password.txt
if name=<C:\dasboot\username.txt if password=C:\dasboot\password.txt GOTO welcomeback
GOTO setstats

:setstats
set /p name="USERNAME: "
set /p password="CREATE A PASSWORD: "

:welcomeback
cls
echo Welcome back, %name%. Your password is %password%.
echo.
pause
exit
```

My issue is that the batch file keeps jumping over the `:setstats` section even though I put `if not exist C:\dasboot\username.txt if not exist C:\dasboot\password.txt GOTO setstats` it still jumps over and the batch file closes itself instantly. Does anyone have a solution? PLEASE NOTE: I am a huge beginner with batch, so please try to dumb down the answer for me a little lol. Thanks so much!

P.S. I am using notepad++ to make this if that helps

EDIT: With the `/p` it still seems to exit out. 
EDIT2: I removed the `<`. Works a lot better but still randomly exits after running the `if name=<C:\dasboot\username.txt if password=<C:\dasboot\password.txt GOTO welcomeback
    GOTO setstats` section. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What's the output of your script? Are statemnts there you are echoing out? Just trying to understand which code lines are executed and which are not.

Comment: First thing to do is to remove all of the < in the 3 lines after the line you highlighted in the last section of your post.

Comment: To load the content of a file into a variable you need to do `set /p var=<somefile.txt`. In your code `/p` is missing.

Comment: `if name=< ...` is wrong syntax, see http://ss64.com/nt/if.html. And for debugging purposes use `echo ON` and add `pause` before any `cls`

Comment: thanks! I will update the load text to have the `/p`. If that doesn't work or I have other problems I will update this question.

Comment: ok it still just exits out of the window after I added the `/p`. I followed what @JosefZ said, but it still exits out. The code that seems to be causing it is the `if name=<C:\dasboot\username.txt if password=<C:\dasboot\password.txt GOTO welcomeback
GOTO setstats` section. Can someone help? Or maybe copy my code and help me debug it?

Comment: I also did what @MichaelS said and it ran better but still exited after running the `if name=<C:\dasboot\username.txt if password=<C:\dasboot\password.txt GOTO welcomeback GOTO setstats` section. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `if name=<C:\dasboot\username.txt if password=C:\dasboot\password.txt` won't work. This makes no sense. What do you want to achieve with this line?

Comment: What I want to do with this line is check that the password variable is the same as the password.txt file, and do the same with the name(username) variable.